# Namespace in XML prevents correct XSL execution

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

My XML files contain several namesspaces which prevent the correct execution of my xsl. Deleting the namespace in the xml files is the only option to work with the xsl. But i would like to use the original xml files with the namespaces. How should i manipulate my xsl to work?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SymbolLibrary xmlns="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0 
file:/D:/DevPool/MiStyle/Src/SymbolLibrary_1_0_0_1.xsd">

       <IconComponents>
          <IconComponent Id="10001">
             <Name>PIK-PAR-Eiffelturm</Name>
             <IconElems>
                <BezierPolygon>
                   <ColorId>198</ColorId>
                </BezierPolygon>
             </IconElems>
          </IconComponent>
        <//IconComponents>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>  

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="IconComponent[@Id='10001']//ColorId/text()[.='210']">21</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Interesting, your xsl looks correct to me.  It is namespace agnostic and should therefore produce the correct result.   Which parser are you using?

Comment: Search StackOverflow for "XSLT default namespace" and you will find 527 answers to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Prevent correct XSL execution" is a nice wording, however it's as you probably suspect your xslt that is not telling it to do correctly

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:relax="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Then prepend relax: to all places in templates, selects and value-ofs where you referenc such a tag (that has no namespace in your input xml)

Note that this will give you the output with the namespaces `relax:`

To avoid that, use

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
    <xsl:element name="local-name()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="relax:IconComponent[@Id='10001']//relax:ColorId/text()[.='210']">21</xsl:template>
```